# Wait for all callback to complete before returning objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that needs to scrape a website and returns a list of addresses.  In the callback from scrape, for each address returned I need to do another scraping operation then process the data, then I want to return the entire processed collection.  I don't mind blocking if I have to.  Ultimately I have to end up with a JSON object with the entire collection.  Is this possible and how can I do this?

```
function doSomething(req, res){

    var collection = [];

    scrape1(params, function(error, addresses){
        if(!error){
            for(var i in addresses){   
                //do some stuff with addresses here

                scrape2(otherparams, function(error, address, data){
                    //manipulate the data here

                    collection.push({ 'address' : address, 'data' : data})  
                });
            }
            //this just returns an empty set obviously
            res.json(collection);

            //how can I return the entire collection from this function?
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Why not just make `res.json(collection);` into callback of "on success" do this?... ->>

Comment: @ProfileTwist can you elaborate a little?  How would I do that?

Comment: look into `then()` provided by jquery. It is a terrific controller mechanism. Basically something like `res.json(collection).then({ some function code)};` ... The code translates to when the ajax call succeeds THEN do this. We use then() quite a lot with ajax calls within global functions.

Comment: The actual final code will depend on how res is implemented. Do you have code for that function call? Is it a built in jquery function call? We would go from there to determine on how to implement `then()` or if we need to use something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module:

```
function doSomething(req, res){

  var collection = [];

  scrape1(params, function(error, addresses){
    if (error)
      return console.error(err); // handle error better

    async.each(addresses, function(address, callback) {
      scrape2(otherparams, function(err, address, data){
        // manipulate the data here
        if (err)
          return callback(err);
        collection.push({ 'address' : address, 'data' : data});
        callback();
      });
    }, function(err) {
      if (err)
        return console.error(err);  // handle error better
      res.json(collection);
    });
  }); 
}
```